# DateTimeOffset Support in Scichart

Tags: scichart

Is it possible to use  DateTimeOffset as the X-Axis data type in scicharts?

I've attempted creating a DataSeries of

`DataSeries<DateTimeOffset,double>`

But get a runtime exception of

> "Cannot create a DataDistributionCalculator for the type TX=System.DateTimeOffset"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SciChart documentation for DataSeries](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/DataSeries%20Types%20in%20SciChart.html), supported datatypes are as follows:

> NOTE: Allowable types in SciChart include DateTime, TimeSpan, Int64, Int32, Int16, Byte, Double, Float, UInt64, UInt32, UInt16, SByte.
>
> DateTime, TimeSpan are only allowable on TX. The type Decimal (128) bit is not allowed. Custom types are not allowed.

As a result it is not possible to declare a custom type for the TX in a DataSeries or an XAxis.

However, you may be able to achieve what you want by using the [LabelProvider feature](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/Axis%20Labels%20-%20LabelProvider%20API.html). If your goal is to allow offsetting DateTime by a fixed amount then the LabelProvider lets you format strings on the XAxis using a custom rule in code.

Is that what you need?

Comment: The LabelProvider will do what we need for now. Our primary concern is addressing DST boundaries. Without the timezone offset, multiple points are plotted with the same X value in the current date time chart when daylight savings boundaries occur. The inability to keep timestamps as DateTimeOffsets will force us to use a numeric chart with a custom LabelProvider. Native support for DateTimeOffsets would be a welcome addition.